# How to leave selected button highlighted

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I'm needing to create a button that highlights as normal when the user has their mouse over the button but if they press it and move away from the button, I want it to stay highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is job for `Checkbox` with `Appearance` set to `Appearance.Button`

```
checkbox1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to create a custom button but if you want something really simple you can just change the button background color.
I'm tracking the clicks so if the user clicks again the button will go back to it's orginal look.

```
    private bool btnClicked;
    private Color btnOrginalColor;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnOrginalColor = button1.BackColor;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnClicked)
        {
            button1.BackColor = btnOrginalColor;
            btnClicked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            btnClicked = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the question relates to a button class from the Infragistics UI library..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Infragistics controls and you want the state to return to normal on a subsequent click of the button you should use the UltraCheckEditor and set the [Style](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinEditors.v13.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraCheckEditor~Style.html) of the editor to be Infragistics.Win.EditCheckStyle.Button:

```
this.ultraCheckEditor1.Style = Infragistics.Win.EditCheckStyle.Button;
```